# How can I write entire data of a variable on a .csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I would like to store entire values of a variable, Cp_cfd. 
`Cp_cfd` is from a database, and

`print(Cp_cfd)`

```
[[ 0.09487912  0.05570169  0.03011282 ...  0.19445465  0.18527783
   0.1675001 ]
 [ 0.094499    0.05298308  0.02696439 ...  0.19821845  0.18978267
   0.17296235]
 [ 0.08363242  0.0591914   0.02952287 ...  0.19714396  0.18762188
   0.1678648 ]
 ...
 [-0.02592602 -0.0313541  -0.04409973 ...  0.24386039  0.20862401
   0.1491545 ]
 [-0.0824953  -0.04109486 -0.05317128 ...  0.23705224  0.20034774
   0.13957643]
 [-0.09290421 -0.05173297 -0.06361054 ...  0.23318158  0.19520814
   0.13199864]]
```

`Cp_cfd.shape` is 
`(11466, 74)`

I made a code to store the values as below

```
def convert_rae(outf, obj):
    o = open(outf, "w")

    for i in range(len(obj)):
        o.write(str(obj[:,i]) + "\n")

    o.close()

convert_rae("rae_test.csv",Cp_cfd)
```

but it gives me an error

```
index 74 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 74
```

How can I efficiently (may look good) store the values without error?

Comment: What kind of object is `Cp_cfd`?

Comment: @Ahndwoo What do you mean by object? It looks like a set of ```float64```.

Comment: I'm not assuming it is, since he makes reference to `Cp_cfd.shape`, which is not an attribute that a standard python list has. Unless he is just describing the dimensions of his lists using code-like language instead of just stating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this would be to use the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

```
import csv

def convert_rae(outf, obj):
    with open(outf, "w", newline='') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerows(obj)

convert_rae("rae_test.csv",Cp_cfd)
```

This may or may not work depending on what kind of object you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

when you loop on `len(obj) = 11466` and access `obj[:, i]` you will try accessing index out of its 74 columns. you probably mean `obj[i, :]`?